# IndexError: list index out of range coursera assignment

Tags: python, list, ide, spyder, index-error

I have a problem with my python code. And no matter what I try, the error `INDEXERROR: LIST INDEX OUT OF RANGE` keeps appearing again and again. Can anyone please help me out. I'm adding my code and the error message below.

```
import urllib,json

# serviceurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?'

while True:
    address = input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1: break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': 
address})

    print ('Retrieving ',url)
    url_handle = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = url_handle.read()

print ('Retrieved',len(data),'characters')
json_data = json.loads(data)

#print json.dumps(json_data['results'], indent=3)
print ('Place id',json_data['results'][0]['place_id'])
```

And this is my Error Message:

```
Enter location: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?
Retrieving  http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?sensor=false&address=http%3A%2F%2Fpy4e-data.dr-chuck.net%2Fgeojson%3F
Retrieved 10092 characters
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a72864740266> in <module>()
     15 
     16     #print json.dumps(json_data['results'], indent=3)
---> 17     print ('Place id',json_data['results'][0]['place_id'])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect your variables in Spyder's variable explorer, you'd see clearly that `json_data['results']` is an **Empty** list, or just print it -

```
json_data['results']
Out[22]: []
```

Hence when you try to access its first element via `json_data['results'][0]` it gives you `IndexError` error because it doesn't exist at all.

**Edit:**
I dug in deeper to find out what was happening-
If you give correct input for example 'UCLA' you'd get a json with the data in `results` field. Like this [url](http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?sensor=false&address=UCLA) that your script tries to access if I enter `UCLA` as input.
However, if any input that isn't there in that initial call to [serviceurl](http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?) then you get something like [this](http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?sensor=false&address=1) which as you can see has **nothing** in `result` field.
You need to have checks in your code so that you can handle this issue properly.

Comment: Mind accepting this as answer if it helps you? Which I am sure it did.